# TikZ in LyX - compiles, but acrobat says the pdf has an error

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx

I'm using LyX. I'm trying to use TikZ for the first time (to draw graphs, specically - trees).

The LyX code compiles and the pdf is created, but when I open the pdf, Acrobat reader says:

> "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display this page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem".
>   The drawing does not appear in the document.

Here's my LaTeX preamble:

```
\date{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*0}{0pt}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
```

and here's what I wrote inside the TeX box in the LyX editor:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the same error message in acrobat even if I remove the `\draw` line and only leave the `\begin` and `\end` lines.

**EDIT**: Here are links to my PDF and LyX files:

> http://www.2shared.com/file/kqhal5As/example.html
>   and
>   http://www.2shared.com/document/0bwz3mrn/example.html

I am using LyX 2.0.0, MiKTeX 2.9, Acrobat Reader 10.1.1 (all in Windows).
I am writing in Hebrew.

Comment: No problem here when viewing output (compiling) in LyX 2.0.4 under Adobe Acrobat 9. What versions are you using? Your document show work when *only* including [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Does it still show errors when you drop *everything* else in your preamble but `\usepackage{tikz}`? Can you post the PDF file somewhere for download? Also, how about exporting the entire LyX file and posting that somewhere as well?

Comment: @Werner: The error still shows if I only include `tikz`. I uploaded the files and indicated the versions I use in the edited post.

Comment: @user302099: Just a suggestion - does it still cause problems after an update of LyX (from 2.0.0 to 2.0.4)?

Comment: @Werner: I will try. What should I do to update? Download LyX 2.0.4 and install it, or is there an internal update mechanism (I'm a little afraid to do that, because installing LyX with Hebrew took some effort).

Comment: @Werner: Did you try my pdf? Does it show an error message in your viewer too?

Comment: @Werner: Updated to LyX 2.0.4 and the problem remains unsolved.