# Lyx Draw a curve from point A to B using xy-pic

Tags: lyx, xy-pic

How can I draw a curve using an `xy-pic` picture to draw a curve from point A to B?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Do you know how to use `xy-pic` so that this is a pure LyX question?  Otherwise, use the MWE of this question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77859/tikz-in-lyx-compiles-but-acrobat-says-the-pdf-has-an-error

Comment: If you are just starting out I would recommend you look at `tikz` instead with which you could use something like `\draw (A) to[out=30, in=150] (B)` after the coordinates `(A)` and `(B)` are defined.

Comment: Here is a complete example if you want to try: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\draw [red, thick] (A) to[out=30, in=150] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.  It will look less scary once you cut and paste this in your editor.